# Is there a way to quickly switch between Debug and Build output window in Visual Studio 2012/2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

There are two related shortcut keys: Debug.Output and View.Output, but both will just focus the keyboard to the Output window without changing to Build or Debug. So either I have to press Alt+S to focus "Show output from:" and press tab and arrow key, or I have to use the mouse.

Is there a way to quickly switch between them?
Or is there a way to separate them into two Output windows?

[image]